# Offending Key for IP when connecting to aws server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Message pops up when i connect to my ec2 machine**

> Offending key for IP in /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:8 
>   Matching host key in /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:24

Please help me to resolve it

Comment: If you know that the key has indeed changed you can fix it by deleting the old key.  With GNU sed, for example, `sed -i -e 8d ~/.ssh/known_hosts` would delete the 8th line.

Comment: thanks, i removed the no. 8 line from ~/.ssh/known_hosts and it worked